# can we set typface at run time which(.ttf) comes from server?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Can we set typeface at run time and .ttf file are coming from server means ttf file come from server and we have to set our font according that

Comment: you could download the .ttf into some folder and typeface can be runtime can be added runtime to textview or any views

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible. You can download the `ttf` file into external storage and create `TypeFace` from that file.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromFile(file);
```

here file should be the `ttf` file from server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible To set Custom font(s) from server.

1. Download font from server
2. Save to SD card
3. Use Typeface.createFromFile(String path)
4. textView.setTypeface(yourTypeface);

**Code**

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "font.ttf")); 
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: What is diff. between your and another answer which is posted 5 mins before from u?